# How to generate a Version 5 UUID in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, uuid

The following code generates a Version 4 UUID.  I need to convert it to generate a Version 5 but cannot find any clear documentation on generating a Version 5 UUID using the Microsoft ole32.dll CoCreateGuid function:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CoCreateGuid Lib "ole32.dll" (guid As GUID_TYPE) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function StringFromGUID2 Lib "ole32.dll" (guid As GUID_TYPE, ByVal lpStrGuid As LongPtr, ByVal cbMax As Long) As LongPtr

Private Type GUID_TYPE
                Data1 As Long
                Data2 As Integer
                Data3 As Integer
                Data4(7) As Byte
End Type

Public Function GetGUID() As String
    Dim guid As GUID_TYPE
    Dim strGuid As String
    Dim retValue As LongPtr
    Const guidLength As Long = 39 'registry GUID format with null terminator {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
    
    retValue = CoCreateGuid(guid)
    If retValue = 0 Then
      strGuid = String$(guidLength, vbNullChar)
      retValue = StringFromGUID2(guid, StrPtr(strGuid), guidLength)
      If retValue = guidLength Then
         ' valid GUID as a string
         GetGUID = Mid$(strGuid, 2, 36)
      End If
    End If
End Function
```